# How pass data with signal/slot from one QObject to another QQuickItem object in qml?

Tags: c++, qt, signals-slots, qtquick2

i have a class like this:

```
class MyClass : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    CircularList<unsigned char> buffer_[2];

    explicit MyClass(QObject *parent = 0);

signals:
    void dataReady(short *buff,int len);
};
```

and the other one is:

```
class WaveItem:public QQuickItem
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    WaveItem(QQuickItem *parent = 0);

public slots:
    void  setSamples(short *buff,int len);

protected:
    QSGNode * updatePaintNode(QSGNode *node, UpdatePaintNodeData *data);
};
```

i need to connect this class in qml with signal(dataReady)/slot(setSamples). how is it possible?

Comment: is that `SerialManager` will be moved away from UI thread i.e., `moveToThread()` used?

Comment: you are subclassing `QThread`? `SerialManager` suggests that you are controlling some serial ports (`QSerialPort`). If that is the case, do you know you can use event driven serial port which will be easy to implement and don't need threads.

Comment: but my problem isn't serial! my problem is how connect  QThread and QquickItem in qml with above signal and slot!

Answer (score 0):

If you check qt docs about [exposing signals](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtqml-cppintegration-exposecppattributes.html#exposing-signals) it describes very well.

First, you need to [register](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qqmlengine.html#qmlRegisterType) your QObject derived class to QML engine.

```
qmlRegisterType<Myclass>("MyclassLib", 1, 0, "Myclass");
```

This way, you can create `Myclass` objects in QML. 
But if you like to create objects in C++ and use that particular object in QML then you need to use [`QQmlContext::setContextProperty`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qqmlengine.html#qmlRegisterType)

```
QQuickView view;
Myclass myClass;
view.engine()->rootContext()->setContextProperty("myclass", &myClass);
```

After you registered type or set your object to QML, you can now use them.

```
Myclass {
    onDataReady: waveItem.setSamples(buff, len);
}
```

Alternatively, you can also use [`connect()`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtqml-syntax-signals.html#connecting-signals-to-methods-and-signals),

```
Myclass {
    id: myClass
    Component.onCompleted: myClass.dataReady.connect(waveItem.setSamples);
}
```

Note: You might also look to [`Connections`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtqml-connections.html).